# line-height displaying differently on iPhone and iPad than on other devices

Tags: android, html, ios, css, iphone

I'm having issues with text displaying differently on different devices. I set the line-height to 1.25em and it appears the way I want it to on across all desktop browsers and Android mobile devices, but it is displaying differently on the iPhone and iPad. On the iPhone and iPad the text looks squished.

**Viewport tag:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 62.5%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 62.5%;
}

.text-16 {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
}
```

**Here is what it looks like on various devices:**

iPad 3:
[image: iPad 3]

iPhone 5:

[image: iPhone 5]

Samsung Galaxy Note II:

[image: Samsung Galaxy Note II]

OS X Lion:
[image: OS X Lion]

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: I know they are quite similar but I always found `%` to be much more consistent than `em`, IMO. Maybe worth a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try setting the html css's font size to 100% ?

Comment: I removed the -webkit-text-size-adjust and left the font-size and that fixed it. Thanks